# Can I use current state of radiation levels to have a rough estimate on natural background radiation or do I need to average over longer timescales?

Tags: radiation, earth

If I look at [EU's radioactivity monitoring map](https://remap.jrc.ec.europa.eu/Simple.aspx):

[image]

I get the impression that most of Europe's Gamma Dose Rate is below or around 100-200 nSv/h. If I convert this value, lets say 150 nSv/h (and looking at the map in detail, this is still an overestimate) to mSv/year, I get $150/1000000*24*365=1.314$ mSv/year. Searching for "natural background radiation typical strength", I get back this info:

[image]

Ie using an overestimate for the hourly rate, I still not get into the 1.5 to 3.5 mSv/year range.

Is this because at this particular time the radiation levels are low and they will average out to be within the range of 1.5 to 3.5 mSv/year, or is this range unreliable (or not that strict?) Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is more to radiation than gammas.

Comment: In addition to Jon's comment, people smoke, fly, eat and take medical checks. Hence, the background radiation from the soil is only a part of the accumulated dose.